# Silence onTouchListener after first touch

Tags: android

I currently have an `onTouchListener` that records the coordinates of the touch event in a `textView`, as shown in my `.java` file below. However, I would like the `onTouchListener` to stop changing the coordinates of the `textView` after the first touch. So essentially, I would like the `onTouchListener` to record the location of the first touch point, update the coordinates on the `textView`, and then not change these coordinates even in the presence of additional touches. Currently, my code is such that the `onTouchListener` continues listening and changing the coordinates that appear on the `textView`. Looking at other examples, there are options such as `finish()` and `@Override`, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it for my use.

`.java file`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final View touchLayout = findViewById(R.id.touchLayout);
        final TextView touchView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        final TextView viewLocat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewLocat);
        final TextView distance = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance);
        final TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);

    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX()) + "x" + Integer.valueOf((int) event.getY()));

                return true;

                    }
                }); 
            }
```

Comment: a boolean seems pretty obvious here

Comment: add a boolean checking variable or set ontouch listener to null

Comment: @IllegalArgument Sorry, I'm pretty new to android. Where do you add that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean isClickOnce=false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final View touchLayout = findViewById(R.id.touchLayout);
        final TextView touchView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        final TextView viewLocat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewLocat);
        final TextView distance = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance);
        final TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);

    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                   if(!isClickOnce){
                textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX()) + "x" + Integer.valueOf((int)         event.getY()));
          isClickOnce=true;
}

                return true;

                    }
            }); 
        }
```

Comment: giving variables (and methods) names that tells nothing about the purpose is rather bad practice.

Comment: The app crashes when I try this, with this error: `05-20 10:47:30.781: W/dalvikvm(2943): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42d5d140)`

Comment: Using isClickOnce(boolean) in the code can't make the app crashes, may be you are getting crash somewhere else.If I can get the logcat may be I can resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public boolean firstTouch = true;
touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if(firstTouch){
firstTouch = false;
 textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
            Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX()) + "x" + Integer.valueOf((int) event.getY()));
}


            return true;

                }
            }); 
        }
```

Comment: Almost, just one question: the first time `firstTouch` appears, I get the error `Illegal modifier for parameter firstTouch; only final is permitted`. How do I fix this error?

Comment: you are setting it inside a inner class the boolean variable declare it outside your function and all is well Most appropriate place is after theclass declaration

Comment: When I try this, I get the error `05-20 10:42:35.565: W/ResourceType(2698): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x000002fc`, as well as a string of many other errors

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using `touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(null)` before the `return:true;` statement.